# Serializing mongoengine objects into JSON

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful, flask-mongoengine

Here is a example of simple REST API built on Flask with flask-restful and mongoengine:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'persons',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017
}
api = Api(app)
db = MongoEngine(app)

class Person(db.Document):
    firstname = db.StringField(required=True)
    lastname = db.StringField(required=True)

class PersonList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(Person.objects)

api.add_resource(PersonList, '/persons')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Do I really have to call flask.jsonify() everytime (in each method that deals with db) to serialize mongoengine objects into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `jsonify` makes the JSON output of `Person.objects` into a Flask Response.

No. You only need to return a data structure that is serializable to JSON from your resource endpoints.

```
def get(self):
    return Person.objects.to_mongo()
```

Also, if you will like to handle JSON conversion at a much later time in your code (*not so great idea!* because it makes the return value inconsistent IMO)`restful.Api` [representation for application/json can be overridden](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#response-formats).

```
from mongoengine.base.document import BaseDocument

...

@api.representation('application/json')
def output_json(data, code, headers=None):
    if isinstance(data, BaseDocument)
        dump = json.dumps(data.to_mongo())
    else:
        dump = json.dumps(data)

    resp = make_response(dump, code)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
```